# I need help in table function

Tags: oracle11g

[code]

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION
DWH_PRODUCTION_SUM_QTDYTD(V_TBL_NAME IN VARCHAR2,V_COL_NAM IN VARCHAR2,V_RPRT_DATE VARCHAR2,
V_FLTRCOL IN VARCHAR2,VALUE_OF IN VARCHAR2, V_GROUP_COL VARCHAR2,V_DF_COL VARCHAR2)-----


RETURN NUMBER  IS 

   A_RET_VALUE NUMBER;


V_REPORT_DATE DATE:=V_RPRT_DATE;
V_FILTERCOL VARCHAR2(30):=UPPER(V_FLTRCOL);
V_COL_NAME VARCHAR2(30):=UPPER(V_COL_NAM);
V_TAB_NAME VARCHAR2(30):=UPPER(V_TBL_NAME);
V_VALUE_TYPE VARCHAR2(8):=UPPER(VALUE_OF);
V_GRP_COL VARCHAR2(30):=UPPER(V_GROUP_COL);
V_DIFF_COL VARCHAR2(30):=UPPER(V_DF_COL);
V_QUARTER_NUMBER  NUMBER(1);
V_QTY VARCHAR2(1000);
V_CURRQTD_STRT VARCHAR2(11);
V_CURRQTD_END  VARCHAR2(11);
V_CURRQTD VARCHAR2(1000);
  BEGIN

--------------------GETTING QUARTER NO.------------------------------

V_QTY:='SELECT TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('''||V_REPORT_DATE||'''), ''Q'')) FROM DUAL';
--DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(V_QTY);
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE V_QTY INTO V_QUARTER_NUMBER ; 
--DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('QT NUM'||V_QUARTER_NUMBER);

--------------------CURRENT QUARTER VALUE------------------------------

SELECT   MIN (t)"CURNT_QTR_ST_DT", MAX (LAST_DAY (t))"CURNT_QTR_END_DT", ADD_MONTHS(MIN (t),-
3)"PREV_QTR_ST_DT", ADD_MONTHS(MAX (LAST_DAY (t)),-3) "PREV_QTR_END_DT" INTO  FROM (SELECT
V_CURRQTD_STRT ,V_CURRQTD_END,V_PRVQTD_STRT, V_PRVQTD_END
 ADD_MONTHS (TRUNC(TO_DATE(TO_DATE(V_REPORT_DATE)), 'YYYY'), LEVEL - 1)  t,
  TO_CHAR (ADD_MONTHS (TRUNC(TO_DATE(TO_DATE(V_REPORT_DATE)), 'YYYY'), LEVEL - 1), 'Q')QTD

 FROM DUAL
   CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 12) A
   WHERE A.QTD  = V_QUARTER_NUMBER;

V_CURRQTD:='SELECT '||V_GRP_COL||', '||V_DIFF_COL||', SUM('||V_COL_NAME||')   AND  TO_DATE-------     ------here m calculating the values dynamically
FROM  '||V_TAB_NAME|| ' WHERE '||V_FILTERCOL||' BETWEEN   TO_DATE('''||V_CURRQTD_STRT||''') ' 
|| '  ('''||V_REPORT_DATE||''') GROUP BY  '||V_GRP_COL||','||V_DIFF_COL||'';

--V_CURRQTD:= V_CURRQTD ||' GROUP BY '||V_GRP_COL;
--DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(V_CURRQTD);
--EXECUTE IMMEDIATE V_CURRQTD INTO V_SUM;
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE V_CURRQTD BULK COLLECT INTO CRQNUMS,CRQNUMS1,CRQNUMS2;
FOR I IN CRQNUMS.FIRST .. CRQNUMS.LAST LOOP
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (
' ITEM_CODE''              '       || CRQNUMS(I) || ': '                     || CRQNUMS1(I)  
||         ': '                          || CRQNUMS2(I));
END LOOP;[/code]
```

this i need to implement in table function....
in thhe above queries m getting the qtr no from the first qry, then in the 2nd getting the 1st and last date of the qtr...
afterward m dynamically populating values into enums....enums2 using bulk collect, but unable to get the output in tabular form....

I've implemented this and getting proper value but need to implement in table function to get the output in tablur form

Comment: i dont see how that code block relates to the type you've defined. they look like totally seperate things. please explain in simple terms what you want to populate in that table type, as a single quarter number doesn't map to it.

Comment: Actually the codes current quarter and current quarter value codes which i wrote in the simple function, now i need to implement the same using table function as user can fire mulitiple conditions while generating the report. if u ask my function code i can provide..

Comment: I want ot populate total sum of any field given as in while calling the function based on the report date and the report date must fall between qtr start date and the report date..

Comment: ok so that type at the beginning didn't realate? i.e. you just want to return an array of sums (i.e. `create type col_sum as table of number;`? then populate that?

Comment: Hi Dazzal, Can u plz elaborate using an example.....

Comment: ive given a simple example on how to collect into an object array. is that of help?

Answer (score 0):

for an example of how to cast a result set into a table type. i.e. just returning an array of (month, qtd):

```
SQL> create type date_typ as object
  2  (
  3    mon   date,
  4    qtd   integer
  5  )
  6  ;
  7  /

Type created.

SQL>
SQL> create type date_tab as table of date_typ;
  2  /

Type created.

SQL>
SQL>
SQL> create function foo(p_report_date date) return date_tab
  2  is
  3    t_quarter date_tab;
  4  begin
  5
  6    select cast(
  7             multiset(select add_months (trunc(sysdate, 'YYYY'), level - 1) t,
  8                             to_char (add_months (trunc(sysdate, 'YYYY'), level - 1), 'Q')QTD
  9                        from dual
 10                      connect by level <= 12)
 11                as date_tab)
 12      into t_quarter
 13      from dual;
 14    return t_quarter;
 15  end;
 16  /

Function created.

SQL> select foo(sysdate) from dual;

FOO(SYSDATE)(MON, QTD)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DATE_TAB(DATE_TYP('01-01-2012', 1), DATE_TYP('01-02-2012', 1), DATE_TYP('01-03-2
012', 1), DATE_TYP('01-04-2012', 2), DATE_TYP('01-05-2012', 2), DATE_TYP('01-06-
2012', 2), DATE_TYP('01-07-2012', 3), DATE_TYP('01-08-2012', 3), DATE_TYP('01-09
-2012', 3), DATE_TYP('01-10-2012', 4), DATE_TYP('01-11-2012', 4), DATE_TYP('01-1
2-2012', 4))


SQL>
```

Comment: Thnx for the prompt response, but can I achieve my goal using this as I've to show multi column and have to do some claculations, filteration and group by...

Comment: @sarroz it would help if you could to formulate a better sample for you